# Why Aws s3 Bucket creating 0 bytes file while uploading file with creating new folder dynamically?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am pretty new to Aws s3 bucket,I am trying to upload files with different folders creation dynamically.Even though my script is working.My s3 bucket creating 0 bytes file,And name equal to folder last uploaded.
 [image]

this is my server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import webpackHotMidleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import open from 'open';
import uuid from 'uuid'

import webpackConfig from './webpack.config';


// Create an S3 client
AWS.config.loadFromPath('c.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

// Create a bucket and upload something into it






let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:"50mb"}));
app.use(express.static('public'));



const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler,{
    hot:true,
    publicPath:webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    noInfo:true
}));

app.use(webpackHotMidleware(compiler));



app.post('/api',(req,res) => {

    let imageuri = req.body.data.data_uri;
    let filename = req.body.data.filename;
    let filetype = req.body.data.filetype;

     const Name = uuid.v1();
    var bucketName = 'nok-sample/'+Name;


    let buf = new Buffer(imageuri.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
    console.log(buf.length);



    s3.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, function() {
        var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: filename, Body: buf,ContentType:filetype,ContentLength:buf.length,ACL:'public-read'};
        s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err)
            else
                console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + filename);
                let resimage = {
                    "awsUrl":`https://s3.amazonaws.com/${bucketName}/${filename}`
                };
                res.json(resimage);
                console.log(resimage)

        });
    });
});



app.get('/*',(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./index.html'))
});


app.listen(3000,() => {
    open('http://localhost:3000')
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what "upload files with different folders creation dynamically" means.  You don't have to create folders at all.  If you upload a file with one or more `/` in the name, the folders automatically appear.  Are you trying to create them yourself?

Comment: I'm also getting issues with files being 0 bytes large when uploaded to an S3 bucket (specifically, the `latest.yml` file generated by `electron-builder`).